# Is there a way to 'tracert' all the addresses shown when executing the 'arp -a' command?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Basically, I'm trying to make a batch script that is able to show names of each device connected to my network. Since `net view /all` doesn't seem to work for me, I'm trying out an alternative.

Is there a way to make a script that automatically executes the `tracert` command on all of the addresses listed by the `arp -a` command?

Comment: yes there is, it is a one liner, but what exactly have you tried? Code requests are off topic on SO.

Comment: @Gerhard I have tried using the `for` command to make it try and 'find' the addresses listed by `arp -a`. Then i tried giving them a variable, which then `tracert` would try to trace back, showing the names of the devices connected to my network. Unfortunately, I'm not able to make it work.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70211803/edit) your question with example of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck on a similar problem, in order to automate the `tracert` command you require a list array that can be  used for later quires.

`arp -a > c:\temp\arp.txt`

If you are putting it in a Batch Script and are not sure if the necessary directories will be present:

`arp -a > c:\temp\arp.txt || md c:\temp && arp -a > c:\temp\arp.txt`

This will try to save the output to a `.txt` file but if the `temp` folder is not present it will make it and re-run the command, it is however bulky.

OR as an `IF` statement

`if exist c:\temp arp -a > c:\temp\arp.txt`

Will only run the command if the target save directory exists.

Binding the two prelisted commands together will be much more reliable but your going to have to deal with `errorlevels` if environment variable change:

`if exist c:\temp (arp -a > c:\temp\arp.txt) else (md c:\temp && arp -a > c:\temp\arp.txt)`

To use the `arp.txt` file in a `nslookup` or `tracert` command requires the use of a `FOR` command where you would be going through the array line by line to retrieve the `IP Address` and then run another command. however, I am also stuck on the Syntax of such a task.

Anyhow, this is half the problem solved, I hope another passer by can implement the `FOR` command!